# Viewing encoded wcf message

Tags: wcf

I am using svc trace viewer and i am able to see the soap message by enabling message logging.

But since http binding uses text encoding and net tcp uses binary encoding,

I enabled trace to view message at service level and at transport level, the message seems to be same with both http and tcp binding.

I would like to know if it is possible to to see the encoded message using svc trace viewer or if any other tool is available .

Comment: Which transfer security mode are you using? None, Message, Transport, or Mixed? And which Authentication method?

Comment: I tried using both transport and message modes. Since i am trying these on same machine , it uses windows client credentials

Comment: Even if some one can send me a sample message with text encoded and binary encoding , that should be fine . I am just curious.

Comment: "Windows client credentials" utilizes Kerberos tokens to encrypt the data. Ideally, you should not be able to decrypt when using Message security, unless you are using Kerberos with the correct account name. For transport, however, it stands to reason that the message should be readable, with effort. Check out http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2011/06/15/decoding-messages-in-wcf-data-services.aspx

Comment: I missed telling one thing. When i used message security, the body of the message was encrypted.